# error on generateSafeArgsDebug task execution, XmlPullParserException only whitespace content allowed

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation, android-safe-args

I had a project in which had three navigation graph xml files, than I deleted one file from file explorer window, after that I had a problem with building the project.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:generateSafeArgsDebug'.
> org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not \u0 (position: START_DOCUMENT seen \u0... @1:1)
```

Then I reverted back the deleted file, but have same problem, also tried to clean project and invalidate cache/restart options several times with no luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed: if you had same error and have mac OS then try removing that file ../navigation/.DS_Store

```
rm -r app/src/main/res/navigation/.DS_Store
```